# Animated Search Form expanding to the left

Tags: html, css

My box is expanding to the right, how can I make it expand to the left?

```css
 input[type=text] {
        width: 130px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        font-size: 16px;
        background-color: white;
        background-image: url('searchicon.png');
        background-position: 10px 10px; 
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
        -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
        transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    input[type=text]:focus {
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
    
<form>
      <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just align it to the right of its container element. Either change the `display` attribute to `block` and set the right and left margins to `0` and `auto`, or keep it as an inline element and apply `text-align: right` to the container block.

```css
input[type=text] {
  display:block;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
  width: 130px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
input[type=text]:focus {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
</form>
```